# Zend Form - Method to extract Label value from Form Class to show in View Script?

Tags: scripting, view, label, zend-form

I'm in the process of switching my forms to use a View Script as their decorators.
The examples I've seen so far do the following in the View Script:

```
<td><label for='textEmail'>Email:</label></td>
<td><?php echo $this->element->textEmail; ?></td>
```

I would like to find a way to have the text to be displayed in the label from the Form Object as well.

```
class RegisterForm extends Zend_Form {
public function init () {
    $this->setAction('')
        ->setMethod('post')
        ->setAttrib('id','formRegister');

    $this->addElement('text', 'textEmail', array('label' => 'Email: '));
    $oEmail = $this->getElement('textEmail')
        ->setRequired(true)
        ->addFilter('StringTrim')
        ->addValidator('EmailAddress');
    $oEmail->setDecorators(array('ViewHelper', 'Errors'));

    $this->setDecorators(array(array('ViewScript', array('viewScript' => 'forms/RegisterForm.phtml'))));
    }
}
```

Above is how my Form Object is defined.
Is anyone aware of how to access the defined label value?
In the following format perhaps?

```
<?php echo $this->element->textEmail->label; ?>
```

Naturally that doesn't work. :p
Thanks~

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$this->element->getLabel()

Here is my view script for standard fields:

```
<div class="field<?php if($this->element->hasErrors()): ?> errors<?php endif; ?>" id="field_<?php echo $this->element->getId(); ?>">
    <?php if (0 < strlen($this->element->getLabel())) : ?>
        <?php echo $this->formLabel($this->element->getName(), $this->element->getLabel());?>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <span class="value"><?php echo $this->{$this->element->helper}(
        $this->element->getName(),
        $this->element->getValue(),
        $this->element->getAttribs()
    ) ?></span>
    <?php if ($this->element->hasErrors()) : ?>
        <?php echo $this->formErrors($this->element->getMessages()); ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <?php if (0 < strlen($this->element->getDescription())) : ?>
        <span class="hint"><?php echo $this->element->getDescription(); ?></span>
    <?php endif; ?>
</div>
```

Comment: You saved my 10 mins and thumbs (y) up for it.